# Prevent app from using Facebook single sign on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have taken over an app that uses Facebook as a login. I want to force the user to be taken to a UIWebView via a URL. Also when a user signs into our app with some other account, say twitter, but then wants to share via Facebook, I want the user to be taken to Facebook login via UIWebView URL not via single sign on.

The apps works as I want it (see above) if the person has not setup single sign on via iPhone > Setting > Facebook. But if the user has setup Single Sign On via iPHone > Settings > Facebook then the app breaks. We are getting an error that the app needs to be officially put in the Facebook app process here https://developers.facebook.com/apps.

We don't want to jump through Facebooks hoops (images, bundle id's etc,...) so we would rather force the user to login via the Facebook webpage via a webview url.

Can I prevent my app from trying to use the Single Sign On on the iphone?

Answer (score 1):

This did it.

```
[[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
            switch (status) {
                case FBSessionStateOpen:
                    // call the legacy session delegate
                    //Now the session is open do corresponding UI changes

                    self.facebookButton.selected = YES;
                    self.shareButton.enabled = YES;
                    self.shareUIButton.enabled = self.shareButton.enabled;
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kShouldPostToFacebookKey];

                    break;
                case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                { // prefer to keep decls near to their use

                    // unpack the error code and reason in order to compute cancel bool
                    NSString *errorCode = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedOriginalErrorCode];
                    NSString *errorReason = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:FBErrorLoginFailedReason];
                    BOOL userDidCancel = !errorCode && (!errorReason ||
                                                        [errorReason isEqualToString:FBErrorLoginFailedReasonInlineCancelledValue]);

                    // call the legacy session delegate if needed
                    //[[delegate facebook] fbDialogNotLogin:userDidCancel];
                }
                    break;

                default:
                    break; // so we do nothing in response to those state transitions
            }
        }];
```